# Symfony Forms - Good practice - events vs controller

Tags: forms, symfony

I'm wondering which one is good practice - Let's say I have contact form type, I want it to send email when form is valid, should I use event in form to send email, or do that in controller where I have form instantiated?

Answer (score 0):

I think for this kind of logic, it is better to use the Event system. You can do some proccessing AFTER the request is sent, so the user does not have to "suffer" from this logic.

This [post](http://problematic.io/2012/03/08/leveraging-the-symfony2-event-dispatcher/) refers to the same problematic.